Azure Machine Learning python SDK V2 add tags to `prepare_image` job
In Azure Machine Learning SDK V2 ( python ), I managed to add tags into a job and a schedule pipeline.
But when preparing the docker image, the job prepare_image is not tagged and thus hard to associate to a project for our finops.
azureml_env = Environment(
    build=BuildContext(
        path=docker_context_path,
    ),
    name=self.experiment_name,
    tags=self.tags,
)
azureml_env.validate()
self.ml_client.environments.create_or_update(azureml_env)

I also tried to put at the pipeline decorator:
@pipeline(
    default_compute=default_compute,
    name=display_name,
    experiment_name=self.experiment_name,
    tags=self.tags,
)

But still no tags on the preparation of the docker image:

How can we tag them with the python SDK ?

Have you tried giving tags to main experiment? try and check.

The main experiment is tagged. When launching a job, the experiment + job + schedule is tagged. But not the job to create to initial (or updated) docker image

The tags you given while building environment is not for the jobs, it is for the environment you are building.
env_docker_context = Environment(
build=BuildContext(path="docker-contexts/python-and-pip"),
name="docker-context-example-2",
description="Environment created from a Docker context.",
tags={"envType":"test-envs"}
)

For above build, the environment is created like below.

To get the tags in job, you need to give it in while creating job like below.
job = command(
    command="echo Hi how r you?",
    environment=env_docker_context,
    display_name="sklearn-diabetes-example",
    tags={"test-jobs":"16-10-24"},
    experiment_name="testExp2"
)

returned_job = ml_client.create_or_update(job)

Output:

Since, prepare_image is a job automatically created and runs on serverless compute for building environment, you cannot create or customize it.
If you want to add the tags you can add it manually in the job section like it's mentioned here

Well this is a shame, how are we supposed to do correct finops if we lack this feature? In our case, we want to facture the compute time of a project to a specific user. Not having this, means we miss some tracking for a large machine running for 20 minutes at least.

Because of automatic job creation prepare_image, no option left to customize. checking more on this, will update the details if any.

Also why you trying to track environment creation. Are you creating the environment for every user or only once?

if you create environment once, again you can give it's name and not docker context, so that it doesn't take time and uses already created environment.

Our environments are tagged. Our job and schedule yes. But prepare_image are machine time that the user is using that can not be tracked with tags automatically. So if a user is developping a python script, he changes his requirements.txt every hour, then every hour a new build is made. And maybe this client would have to pay more for prepare_image than it's actual experiment since he it's not production read, he is still making tests.

So basically, you need to track time taken for every build. right?

Costs of the compute used for every build based on "tags" where we could position a specific tag like "project". And then we could track the real cost of a project for a user

are you able to calculate cost for the job you are submitting excluding the environment build?

Please add how you are calculating the cost.

Add how you are calculating cost for your job run.
